# Why my simply linked list doesn't work after first node?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I write this code to automatically gets values and put them in a linked list but it just maintain first one and replace any new one in second node and doesn't make third, forth or ... nodes.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct node
    {
        int a;
        struct node *next;
    }zero;

    node *first = NULL;


    int main()
    {
        int t;
        for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        {
            node *n = first;
            cin >> t;
            if (first == NULL)
            {
                node temp;
                temp.a = t;
                first = &temp;
                temp.next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                while ((*n).next != NULL)
                {
                    n = (*n).next;
                }
                node tt;
                tt.a = t;
                (*n).next = &tt;
                tt.next = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
```

I inserted 28.
my first node data=28.
I inserted 57.
my second node data=57.
I inserted 120.
my **second** node data=120.
...

Comment: What did you observe when you start your program in the debugger and step through the code line by line?

Comment: I know it comes up in every code review, but [don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1813169)

Comment: Undefined behavior due to the dereferencing of dangling pointers (due to storing pointers to local variables).

Comment: It’s usually a bad idea to store what `&` gives for later use. This is no exception. The web is full of examples of linked lists, and so are books.

Comment: You use pointers to local variables. You never allocate new memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node temp;` within a compound statement declares an automatic variable. `first = &temp;` assigns `first` to point to the automatic variable.

Automatic variables are destroyed *automatically* at the end of the scope - the compound sub-statement of the if-statement in this case. After that, `first` no longer points to a valid object - it becomes a dangling pointer.

When in the next iteration you do `node *n = first` and then `*n` in the else-branch, you indirect a dangling pointer. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: I don't have this problem (I checked it line by line) but my problem is that after making first node every time the temp is a special memory space which doesn't change.

Comment: @P7928Z of course you have. In line `node temp;` you allocate memory. In line `first = &temp;` you store the address of this memory. After this the memory is deallocated. In line `while ((*n).next != NULL)` you dereference this memory. That's undefined behaviour